# AspectJ annotation requires project restart ..!

Tags: java, grails, aop, aspectj

so i have successfully setup aspect J with my grails project...but i am facing a very serious problem...every time i add or remove an annotation from a method the project has to be restarted in order to get it working ...like i made an @LogBefore annotation but it is works when i add and restart the project...and if i add another annotation on method then again i have to restart the project so can anyone please suggest why this is happening and how can i resolve this issue..

```
package com.app.aspects

 @Aspect
 @Component("loggingAspect")
class LoggingAspect {

@Pointcut("@annotation(com.app.annotations.LogAction)")
public void logParams() {
}

@Before("logParams()")
public void loggingParams() {
    println "Before Params"
}

@After("logParams()")
public void loggingParamsAfter() {
    println "After Params"
}
```

my class

```
   my class {
  @LogAction
  def myMethod(){
 }
```

}

Comment: What is "MyClass"? Is it a domain class? Is it a service? A controller? Just a Groovy class in `src/groovy` or a Java class in `src/java`? You are going to need to provide a bit more detail.

Comment: it is a controller...so i have got success  by enabling loadTimeweaving in my controller now i can add notation without restarting my project ..but now stuck in getting params in @Around !!

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to restart the project when I add an annotation"? If you change your code you need to recompile the code, what else did you expect?